# Boolean, repeat certain functions if false

Tags: c++

This is my first post; sorry for any formatting mistakes. Why doesn't the second get_wager_amount() get used (the program terminates), and how should I fix this? Or anything to make the code better would be appreciated. Code is below:

```
int get_bank_balance(){
    cout << "Enter an initial bank balance (dollars): " << endl;
    cin >> balance;
    return balance;
    }

int get_wager_amount(){
    cout << "\nEnter a wager (dollars)" << endl;
    cin >> wager;
}
bool is_valid_wager_amount(){
    if(wager <= balance){
        return true;
    }
    if(wager > balance){
        cout << "Error: wager > balance. Try again" << endl;
        return false;
    }

}


int main()
{

    get_bank_balance();
    get_wager_amount();
    is_valid_wager_amount();
    if (is_valid_wager_amount == false){
        get_wager_amount();
        is_valid_wager_amount();
    }
```

Comment: are you sure this c++ code compiles?

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the variables or anything above it. What should be fixed?

Comment: @speechlesspeaches the requirement for all "What's wrong with my code?" questions is a [mcve]. This is the smallest possible code required to reproduce the error. We don't just ask for these because we're lazy, a good MCVE is the bug, the whole bug and nothing but the bug. It is hard to make a MCVE without spotting and fixing the bug yourself. If you start a question by making a MCVE you rarely need to ask the question.

Comment: Don't take user input in functions. Don't use globals! This is bad code. And I am sure this must be done by your professor trying to teach you functions right?

Comment: Slight correction to *Don't take user input in functions.* What you really want to avoid is combining two or more responsibilities in the same function. A function that takes input should only take input. A function that performs a computation on an input should only perform that computation. This keeps functions short, simple, and easier to test and debug.

Comment: Thank you user4581301 and Hemil, @Hemil and yes, it's my professor :p

Answer (score 2):

```
is_valid_wager_amount();
if (is_valid_wager_amount == false)
```

is calling `is_valid_wager_amount`, discarding the result, and then testing the `is_valid_wager_amount` function's address to see if it is false. This isn't particularly useful. An up-to-date compiler should reject this code.

Instead give,

```
if (is_valid_wager_amount() == false){
```

a try. This calls the `is_valid_wager_amount` function and checks to see if the result is false.

Unrelated: consider replacing the `if` with a `while` to repeatedly ask until the user provides a valid response.

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't forget to include the library.
2. Don't forget to initiate variable before use them as input/output.
3. Some function need value for their operation, so use global variable/u can call them on function bracket.
4. int function return int value, so save them to variable if you need to use them later.

   ```
   #include <iostream> //1
   using namespace std;
   int get_bank_balance()
   {
       int balance; //2
       cout << "Enter an initial bank balance (dollars): " << endl;
       cin >> balance;
       return balance;
   }

   int get_wager_amount()
   {
       int wager; //2
       cout << "\nEnter a wager (dollars)" << endl;
       cin >> wager;
       return wager;
   }
   bool is_valid_wager_amount(int balance,int wager)//3
   { 
       if(wager <= balance)
       {return true;}
       else
       {
           cout << "Error: wager > balance. Try again" << endl;
           return false;
       }
   }

   int main()
   {
       int balance = get_bank_balance(); //4
       int wager = get_wager_amount(); //4
       if (is_valid_wager_amount(balance, wager)){
           //another function here, for example:
           cout<<"Your balance: "<<balance-wager<<endl;
       }
   }
   ```